# Problem with @UniqueConstraint with extends

Tags: java, jpa, annotations

Main class

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"codigoEAN", "tipo"})})
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "tipo")
@DiscriminatorValue("Produto")
public class Produto {
```

Class extending

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Caixa")
public class ProdutosEmCaixa extends Produto {
```

What I wanted ?

1. That when it is a produto type "Produto" it does not repeat the keys (codigoEAN, tipo) but when it is of the type "Caixa" it can repeat the keys.

Something like

```
// That does not exist
@Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"codigoEAN", "tipo=Produto"})})
```

Has anyone ever experienced this?

Comment: By definition, you cannot have duplicated keys in a table. that would mean that they are not keys. What exactly are you trying to map here? Are you sure it is not a one-to-many associations? https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
```

This means that both entities will be mapped in a single table (using a discriminator column). You cannot define a unique constraint that only works for specific rows.

If the constraint only makes sense for a type of entity, you have to map them in separate tables.

With `InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS`:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Produto {
...
   @Column(name="codigoEAN")
   private String codigoEAN;
}

@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"codigoEAN"})})
public class ProdutosEmCaixa extends Produto {
 ...
}
```

or `InheritanceType.JOINED`:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "tipo")
@DiscriminatorValue("Produto")
public class Produto {
...

}

@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"codigoEAN"})})
@DiscriminatorValue("Caixa")
public class ProdutosEmCaixa extends Produto {
 ...
   @Column(name="codigoEAN")
   private String codigoEAN;
}
```

See the Hibernate ORM documentation for more details about [mapping inheritance](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance-joined-table).